# Thermal imaging

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, hardware, sd-card

I was wondering if anyone knows of a thermal imaging app for either iOS or android, just purchased an p3 b+ and just trying to get a few things clarified befor I start her up, also any info on a raspberry beginner which you think could help a first time user would be much appreciated.
Thanks, RO0.

Comment: What are you wanting to clarify? Just power the Pi3B+ on !

Comment: I just want to check the heat being kicked out from it then monitor it as i get more use out of it , and putting it under different stresses, just to monitor it for fun really, thanks for getting back to me.

Comment: Assuming your going to run Raspbian with Desktop you can add a temperature monitor panel to the task bar.

Comment: Sweet, yea that sounds good as an added layer for monitoring to see actually how accurate a thermal app is, will post this in iOS and Android stacks as well see what people will come up with, sound mike

Comment: Don’t most/all phones have IR filters on the lenses? You may be able to find one without or use the pi noir camera module, but that won’t be the same as real thermal imaging unless you have some proper hardware.